# How to install a certificate for iOS development?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been having trouble downloading certificates automatically through Xcode and will need to install the certificate myself. I've downloaded the **ios_development.cer** file. I can't find any straightforward documentation on how to install the certificate. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: just double click on the certificate. it will open in keychain access.can you try this?

Comment: Yes, i've done that but are there more steps? How does it link to my provisioning profile?

Comment: you downloaded the .mobileprovision?

Comment: after downloded the .mobileprovision profile just double click on that it will show on organizer in provisioning profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

watch the following tutorial, that will help you.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=dUdHifLTyrE